# Is an experience certificate from an unregistered company valid?

Tags: human-resources, work-experience, india, company

I am working in an Indian IT company  which is not a registered company.

Would an experience certificate from such a company be valid or not?

Comment: For those more familiar with India, is an experience certificate similar to a relieving letter? I wasn't sure whether that tag would be appropriate or not.

Comment: It is recipient specific, not general, see Myles`s answer

Comment: @DavidK Relieving letter will have completion date and assurance that the worker has met their required obligations in ending the employee/employer relationship whereas an experience certificate typically outlines the type of work and that is was done in a satisfactory nature.  It would be similar to a "To whom it may concern" type of reference letter.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working under the assumption that the law requiring businesses to register is generally followed.  In this case your results would completely depend on the party which is using your certificate.

For another small company without well established HR processes or another company in the same area that would be able to confirm the existence of the first without relying on the Ministry for confirmation, you might not run into issues.

For a MNC or very large national company you are much more likely to run into trouble.  Organizations of this nature will have processes that attempt to weed out fraud like claiming experience from companies that don't exist.

For any interactions with bureaucracy like government or professional bodies there is potential for extra headaches.  Reporting experience towards professional certifications or for eligibility for social assistance programs may prove more difficult.